# How to generate every day of the last 30 days javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to generate an array of days in javascript?
For example
Start creating a 30-day data array today

```
11-04-2022
10-04-2022
09-04-2022
```

And so on until the end of 30 days
I read that it could be with Liberia at the moment, but I'm not sure how to use it
Is there a way I should write the code without using a library?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and no, you need the Time library

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply looping and using the index to increase a Date object.

For example:

```js
const arr = []

for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
  const start = new Date(); 
  arr.push(new Date(start.getFullYear(),start.getMonth(),start.getDate()+index))
}

console.log(arr)
```